# dpkg: error processing package ramme (--install)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I was trying to install [Ramme](http://github.com/terkelg/ramme), but I was getting dpkg error. I tried to install other but won’t install, with no luck.

I'm getting this error:

```
(Reading database ... 188852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Ramme_3.2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ramme (3.2.5-243) over (3.2.5-243) ...
Setting up ramme (3.2.5-243) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/ramme': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ramme (--install):
 installed ramme package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ramme
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ramme (3.2.5-243) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/ramme': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ramme (--configure):
 installed ramme package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ramme
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You seem to be installing from a file `Ramme_3.2.5_amd64.deb`. It is not provided by Ubuntu repositories. Please [edit] your question to mention where this file comes from. You might get better results by directly contacting its developers.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try the below instead if you've yet to resolve this issue.

Download the appropriate .deb file from [Github.com/ramme/releases](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/releases). in this case if you are on a 64 bit processor you'd download the 
 [Ramme_3.2.5_amd64.deb](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/releases/download/v3.2.5/Ramme_3.2.5_amd64.deb) else you would install the 32 bit version [Ramme_3.2.5_i386.deb](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/releases/download/v3.2.5/Ramme_3.2.5_i386.deb)
from Github.

Then simply just run the command: `$ sudo dpkg -i Ramme_3.2.5_amd64.deb` 
or `$ sudo dpkg -i Ramme_3.2.5_i386.deb` respective to what processor you have. Make sure to run this in the directory that the file has been downloaded to, e.g `/home/USER/Downloads/`

Comment: I bet that is exactly what the OP has done.

Comment: I'm not sure, hope I can help

Comment: Do you have `ramme` installed? Can you tell what `/usr/local/bin/ramme` links to? Perhaps the OP can manually add that link and retry the installation.

Comment: unfortunately same problem @HunterLowe